# Criar trigger com update setando campo através de uma função

Tags: sql, sql-server, funções, trigger

Estou querendo utilizar uma `trigger` para atualizar o campo de uma tabela sempre que houver um insert nesta mesma tabela.

O problema que estou tendo na trigger é que o update não funciona, segue a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER descNF ON tabela1
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @IDMOV VARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @IDMOV = (SELECT IDMOV FROM INSERTED)
 UPDATE tabela1 SET tabela1.HISTORICOLONGO = dbo.f_descricao(@IDMOV) WHERE IDMOV = @IDMOV
END
```

Já tentei realizar algumas mudanças, como esta, mas não funcionou:

```
CREATE TRIGGER descNF ON tabela1
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IDMOV VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @IDMOV = (SELECT IDMOV FROM INSERTED)
    DECLARE @TEXTO VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @TEXTO = dbo.f_descriptionNFSe(@IDMOV)
    UPDATE tabela1 SET tabela1.HISTORICOLONGO = @TEXTO WHERE IDMOV = @IDMOV
END
```

Já identifiquei que o problema é no SET do update com uma função, pois quando faço isso:

```
CREATE TRIGGER descNF ON tabela1
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IDMOV VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @IDMOV = (SELECT IDMOV FROM INSERTED)
    UPDATE tabela1 SET tabela1.HISTORICOLONGO = 'TESTE' WHERE IDMOV = @IDMOV
END
```

Ele funciona e realiza o update.

Retirando o update da trigger e executando como um UPDATE comum, conforme abaixo:

```
DECLARE @IDMOV VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @texto = dbo.f_descriptionNFSe(123)
UPDATE tabela1 SET tabela1.HISTORICOLONGO = @texto WHERE IDMOV = 123

OU 

UPDATE tabela1 SET tabela1.HISTORICOLONGO = dbo.f_descriptionNFSe(123) WHERE IDMOV = 123
```

Também funciona, portanto, a minha pergunta é a seguinte: é possível utilizar uma função para setar o campo em um comando de UPDATE dentro de uma trigger igual eu estou fazendo?

Comment: E qual é o tipo de dados do parâmetro da função `dbo.f_descriptionNFSe`?

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim Pedro, criei um esquema aqui rapidão para mostrar que funciona. Segue imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observando que a Função retorna o mesmo tipo de dados do Campo em questão que no exemplo é tipo `INT`.

Agora veja a seguir com um UPDATE no TRIGGER para Incrementar um valor a cada INSERT:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

resumindo é possível sim!
espero ter ajudado!!!
Segue abaixo Código usado na imagem:

```
CREATE TABLE Tabela01(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Nome NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Tabela02(  
    Total INT
)
GO


CREATE FUNCTION Somar(@N1 INT, @N2 INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @N1 + @N2
END
GO


CREATE TRIGGER UsandoFuncao ON Tabela01
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Resultado INT
    DECLARE @QTD INT

    SELECT @Resultado = [dbo].[Somar] (10, 10)
    SELECT @QTD = COUNT(*) FROM Tabela02

    IF @QTD < 1 
        INSERT Tabela02 VALUES([dbo].[Somar] (10, 10))
    ELSE
        UPDATE Tabela02 SET Total += [dbo].[Somar] (10, 10)
    --UPDATE Tabela02 SET Total = @Resultado
END
GO


INSERT INTO Tabela01 VALUES('Paulo2')
GO

SELECT * FROM Tabela01
GO
SELECT * FROM Tabela02
GO
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código? Nem todos conseguem ver imagens

Comment: Precisei criar uma view, é um sistema embarcado, provavelmente a ordem em que as tabelas são populadas não funcionam com as que estou verificando. Em resumo: criei a view com os dados buscados da função e fiz o sistema começar a consultar a view ao invés de consultar a tabela original com o update.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- código #1
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.descNF 
    on dbo.tabela1
    after INSERT AS
begin

-- verifica número de linhas a tratar
declare @NL int;
set @NL= (SELECT count(*) from (SELECT top (2) * from INSERTED) as I);

-- encerra o processamento se não há linha para tratar
IF @NL = 0 return;

-- 
UPDATE T1
  set HISTORICOLONGO= dbo.f_descricao(T2.IDMOV) 
  from dbo.tabela1 as T1
       inner join INSERTED as T2 on T1.IDMOV = T2.IDMOV;
END;
go
```

Sugestão de leitura: [Armadilhas na programação de procedimentos de gatilho](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/08/18/armadilhas-na-programacao-de-trigger/).

Answer (score 0):

Precisei criar uma view, é um sistema embarcado, provavelmente a ordem em que as tabelas são populadas não funcionam com as que estou verificando. Em resumo: criei a view com os dados buscados da função e fiz o sistema começar a consultar a view ao invés de consultar a tabela original com o update.